# Create req.session.user nodejs

Tags: node.js

i have data about the users from...

```
let userData = await axios.get(`https://data_about_users/v2/me`, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.BEARER_TOKEN}` } });

// Login
// Is admin?
// etc...
```

and i wanna block some urls

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
            if (req.url === '/human.html' && req.session.user && req.session.rol === 'admin') {
                console.log(clc.yellow(`Log: User ${req.session.user} has been connected`));
                res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, this.srcsPath, 'human.html'));
            }
            else {
                console.log(clc.red(`Error: User ${req.session.user} is not authorized`));
                res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, this.srcsPath, 'index.html'));
            }
        });
```

the problem is, i dont know how i can create the req.session for each users, please help :( .

Comment: do you use express? or how is app created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of login, put your logged in user details in request something like this-

```js
req.user = loggedInUserResponse; // this is the response you get from https://data_about_users/v2/me
```

Then modify your condition something like this-

```js
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
            if (req.url === '/human.html' && req.user && req.user.rol === 'admin') {
                console.log(clc.yellow(`Log: User ${req.user.name} has been connected`));
                res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, this.srcsPath, 'human.html'));
            }
            else {
                console.log(clc.red(`Error: User ${req.user.name} is not authorized`));
                res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, this.srcsPath, 'index.html'));
            }
        });
```